# How to display an SVG image that is sourced from an IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, display

I have difficulties to display an SVG image that I've previously stored in a local IndexDB. The displayed SVG image is displayed with a question mark icon in Safari and a broken link icon in Firefox.

In my HTML app the user can upload any type of media file that I store in a local index DB.

1. Import media file :

   ```
   <input id="mediafile" type="file" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg,
         image/png, image/gif, image/svg, image/svg+xml, audio/mp3,
         audio/mpeg, video/mp4, video/quicktime, capture=camcorder">
   ```

This works fine so far for alle accepted media types.

2. Store imported file in IndexDB and create URL link to it for displaying purposes (simplified):

```js
if (file) {
  // Create reader to store file in DB
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); // readAsText // readAsArrayBuffer(file); readAsDataURL
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    // Browser completed reading file - store it with unique key ID
    var uuId = uuidv4();

    // Store file in DB
    dbStoreFile(uuId, e.target.result)
      .then(
        function() {
          // Get file to create thumbnail (image)
          dbGetFileUrl(uuId)
            .then(
              function(url) {
                switch (type) {
                  case 'image':

                    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    break;
                  case 'video':
                    ...
                }

                // Create thumbnail
                var preview = document.createElement('img');
                preview.src = url;
                preview.width = '60';
                preview.height = '60';

                // Display thumbnail
                var structure = '<div id="' + uuId + '" projectid="' + projectId + '" style="float: left; height: 60px; width: 60px; margin: 5px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #b1b1b1; border-radius: 5px;"></div>';
                $('#mediacontainer' + projectId).append(structure);
                $('#mediacontainer' + projectId + ' #' + uuId).append(preview);

                // Remove imported file
                $('#mediafile').val('');

                // Store change in DB
                dbStoreFile('project', project);
              }
            );
        }
      );
  };
}
```

-> This works fine for all accepted media files (also SVG) just because I create the URL directly from the imported file.

3. When I close the HTML app (or just reload it) the app has to load the media files from the IndexDB. This works fine EXCEPT for SVG files:

```js
function createThumbnail(projectId, uuId, type) {
  var mediaTitle = '';

  var url = '';
  // Get file to create thumbnail (image)
  dbGetFileUrl(uuId)
    .then(
      function(url) {
        // Create thumbnail
        var preview = document.createElement('img');
        preview.src = url;
        preview.width = '60';
        preview.height = '60';

        // Display thumbnail
        var structure = '<div id="' + uuId + '" projectid="' + projectId + '" style="float: left; height: 60px; width: 60px; margin: 5px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #b1b1b1; border-radius: 5px;"></div>';
        $('#mediacontainer' + projectId).append(structure);
        $('#mediacontainer' + projectId + ' #' + uuId).append(preview);

        $('#mediacontainer' + projectId + ' #' + uuId).attr('src', url);

      }
    );
}
```

Relevant content of the called function dbGetFileUrl:

```js
// Get file blob
var fileBlob = new Blob([request.result.file]); // adding type doesn't help: {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}

// Create URL for blob
var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
return fileURL;
```

I have checked the returned URL that looks correct in any case: blob://https.mypage.com/A5C7DAFE1H....

This time all media types are displayed EXCEPT SVG files. You may think the stored SVG file is corrupt or something like that but it isn't: The user can upload any media files into the cloud and accessing those from a homepage. The cloud API allows me to create an URL for any file in the cloud and then also any uploaded SVG files are displayed correctly!

I assume the SVG handling is somehow different than for any oder media types(?) or I ignored something simple. I've checked any other problems around displaying SVG files in Stackoverflow but none seems to cover this problem. 
I also have tried like 10 different SVG files but all lack of displaying it when reading from indexDB. The SVG files don't need to be displayed in a Canvas for modifying purposes. I simply want to display it in a `<img>` tag (as this works for all other image types).

The SVG file looks exactly the same on reading out by reader function or returning from indexDB:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 26 26" enable-background="new 0 0 26 26" xml:space="preserve">

<g>
 <path fill="#000000" d="M14.137,17.766c-1.545,0-3.056-0.564-4.195-1.705c-0.637-0.635-0.637-1.663-0.002-2.298   s1.664-0.635,2.298-0.001c1.11,1.108,3.036,0.988,4.293-0.271l5.013-5.013c0.671-0.668,1.054-1.541,1.054-2.395   c0-0.51-0.136-1.25-0.78-1.896c-0.691-0.692-1.484-0.806-2.038-0.778c-0.817,0.037-1.618,0.41-2.255,1.047L14.649,7.33   c-0.672-0.672-3.433-1.165-4.181-0.416l4.756-4.755c1.21-1.21,2.771-1.919,4.4-1.997c1.699-0.078,3.293,0.533,4.487,1.727   c1.119,1.117,1.735,2.607,1.735,4.195c-0.001,1.71-0.732,3.421-2.008,4.693l-5.012,5.012   C17.516,17.104,15.808,17.766,14.137,17.766z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path fill="#000000" d="M11.863,8.234c1.543,0,3.055,0.564,4.196,1.705c0.636,0.635,0.635,1.663,0,2.298   c-0.634,0.635-1.663,0.635-2.298,0c-1.109-1.107-3.035-0.986-4.293,0.271l-5.013,5.013c-0.67,0.668-1.054,1.541-1.054,2.395   c0,0.508,0.136,1.25,0.781,1.896c0.691,0.69,1.484,0.806,2.038,0.78c0.817-0.039,1.618-0.412,2.255-1.049l2.873-2.872   c0.672,0.671,3.433,1.164,4.182,0.415l-4.756,4.755c-1.209,1.21-2.771,1.919-4.399,1.997c-1.7,0.08-3.294-0.532-4.489-1.727   c-1.119-1.117-1.734-2.607-1.734-4.195c0.001-1.71,0.731-3.421,2.007-4.693l5.012-5.012C8.483,8.898,10.193,8.234,11.863,8.234z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Once again: The posted code works fine, just not for SVG files in order to display them.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://medium.com/@benjamin.black/using-blob-from-svg-text-as-image-source-2a8947af7a8e

Comment: @blex: Thanks, I've tried things around that, didn't help. And I would like  to display the SVG file into an IMG tag not inside an SVG tag.